# Sudoku polynomial algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np-complete

I have a project to do for a complexity and problem solving course, and I've decided to base the project on Sudoku. From the research I've done, Sudoku is an NP-Complete problem (which is required for the project), and I've found a few ways of creating algorithms for it. I'm planning on doing a brute force solving method, and I need to do two other methods. I've found some ways, such as solving it as an Exact Cover problem, and I've found a paper that describes Sudoku as a SAT problem. But my question is this: Is there a proven polynomial solution for Sudoku? My teacher seems to think there was a "clever" solution by a "senior" gentleman about 5 years ago, but that's all he can remember. Does anybody know what this solution is, or what any other polynomial solution is? I'd appreciate any information or tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Brute force is about polynomial as it can get. (there can be some pruning, though)

Comment: NP-Complete means there is (probably) no solution that scales polynomially with the size of the input.  But, sudoku only has one input size, so what does that even mean here?

Comment: Ah, ok, the more general problem of sudoku-like puzzles is NP-Complete.  From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Mathematical_context): *"The general problem of solving Sudoku puzzles on n2 × n2 boards of n × n blocks is known to be NP-complete. For n=3 (classical Sudoku), however, this result is of little relevance: algorithms such as Dancing Links can solve puzzles in fractions of a second."*

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Well the paper I mentioned about Sudoku as a SAT problem is located here:

trac.assembla.com/disenosudoku/export/2/docs/SudokuAsSAT.pdf

It's an interesting paper, though the authors themselves claim that the method is "experimental". They claim that a Sudoku puzzle can be polynomial if there is a unique solution to the puzzle. The only way it can be unique is if enough of the puzzle cells are "pre-filled", like the puzzle comes. I just wasn't sure if there were any other poly solutions (whether this SAT one is legitimate or not)

Answer (score 4):

Because the generalized Sudoku problem (with n<sup>2</sup> × n<sup>2</sup> grids) is NP-hard, if there were a known polynomial-time algorithm for solving Sudoku puzzles, it would prove P = NP. That would be a *huge* deal.

Something to keep in mind is that Sudoku puzzles as we know them are all 9 × 9 grids. As a result, when trying to measure the time complexity of solving a Sudoku puzzle, it actually isn't a good idea to use big-O notation because big-O notation talks about how an algorithm scales *in the long term* and all we care about is solving Sudoku puzzles of a fixed size. Restated differently, if you wanted to talk about a polynomial-time for solving Sudoku puzzles, you'd have to answer the question "polynomial *in what variable?*" If you're always solving a 9 × 9 Sudoku grid, the answer to that question isn't really clear.

Comment: Really? Checking if a sudoku is valid is O(1): There are 9 rows, 9 columns and 9 blocks, and we only need to check for each if each of the numbers [1 .. 9] is contained. Then there is a limited number of total combinations to distribute ciphers over a 9x9 field (9^81, including the invalid ones). Iterate over any such combination, check, if each fix position matches (again O(1)), and check, if a valid sudoku. Then you have a fix number of steps to perform at maximum (9^81 * (<steps to check if fix numbers match> + <steps to check valid sudoku>), so solving only 9x9 sudokus is actually O(1)...

Comment: @Aconcagua I completely agree. In my answer I was trying to highlight that talking about the complexity of solving sudokus is really only meaningful if you allow the puzzle to be generalized, since otherwise, as you noted, the answer is "O(1)."

Comment: @Aconcagua generalized sudoku is interesting. i've been notating hᵍ(hᵍ) for the supersymmetric structure.  [Hamkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/infinite-sudoku-and-the-sudoku-game/) did a solution to infinite impartial sudoku, the fundamental form of the sudoku game.  Any solution should scale for any *h* and *g*, with even and odd *h* producing different outcomes. ( I use h&g to commemorate [Howard Garns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Garns) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [human-like strategy](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/42521/Sudoku), which can be polynomial, but it will not find solution for all sudokus (even those with unique solution). It is also really easy to reduce sudoku to graph-coloring problem (each cell is represented by a node of a graph, nodes are connected according to the rules of sudoku, in order not to have the same color. Prefilled nodes are grounded to some color).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rook polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial).

For a 9 * 9 grid , which starts completely empty this gives a 9th order polynomial.

However, for a partially filled grid the order reduces to the longest empty
Span.